# basic std::regex, translate query to valid mask

Tags: c++, regex

I need to implement simple regex search with two special simbols - asterisk (*) as any number of characters and question mark (?) as any single character. Any other symbols in query must be interpreted as is.

Main problem is how to translate input mask to valid std::regex mask. 
I'm translating * as .* and ? as . (dot). All other characters must be escaped or  interpreted as is. And here is the problem - std::regex raises an exception if I escape any character, except of these: $^[\|.

And it raises an exception, if I escape ] symbol. And it raises an exception if DO NOT escape ] symbol. So I can't search for ] sign at all.

I think, this is my fail and I do something wrong. But I can't understand where is my fail.

I'm using VS 2017 and C++17 option.

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>

void translate_mask (std::wstring & mask)
{
    std::wstring basic (L"^");
    for (auto c : mask)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
        case L'*':
            basic += L".*";
            break;
        case L'?':
            basic += L'.';
            break;

        case L'$':
        case L'^':
        case L'[':
        case L'\\':
        case L'|':
        case L'.':
            basic += L'\\' + std::wstring (1, c);
            break;

        case L']':      
            basic += L'.';      // workaround? ']' char cannot be escaped, so interpret it is as any single char

            // uncomment any of these lines and exception will be raisen from std::wregex ctor
            //basic += L'\\' + std::wstring (1, c);
            //basic += c;
            break;


        default:
            basic += c;
        }
    }
    basic += L'$';

    mask = std::move (basic);
}

void load_string (std::wstring & str)
{
    // load string from some database, for example
    str = L"[ hello | world of stack ]";
}

bool find (const std::wstring & str, const std::wstring & mask)
{
    try
    {
        std::wregex r (mask, std::wregex::basic);
        std::wsmatch m;
        return std::regex_search (str, m, r);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

int main ()
{
    std::wstring mask, str;
    // std::wcin >> mask;
    // example input:
    mask = L"[ hello | world of * ]";
    load_string (str);
    translate_mask (mask);
    bool res = find (str, mask);   // returns true

    return 0;
}
```

If I try to escape ']' character as '\]', find function will raise an exception.
If I do not escape ']' at all, find function will raise an exception.
Pls see `case L']':` line in `translate_mask` function

Comment: Let's see some examples. Let's see an example input, the resulting escaped regex, and the exception that you get. You probably just escaped it wrong....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As a new user, please take the [tour]. Your question offers a few interpretations of problems you encounter, but you omitted the actual observations, see also [ask]. Also, please extract a [mcve], having to guess what to input is not helpful, use hardcoded texts instead.

Comment: `prog.cpp:1:27: error: variable or field ‘translate_mask’ declared void` `prog.cpp:1:22: error: ‘wstring’ is not a member of ‘std’` `prog.cpp:1:37: error: ‘mask’ was not declared in this scope` [Live demo](https://ideone.com/bEF0lJ)

Comment: Please don't put additional relevant and important info into comments, that's the wrong way. Instead, [edit] your question so it contains that info.

Comment: Ok, I fixed post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `basic` syntax (for reasons unclear, since you seem to think in terms of ECMASCript grammar). [In that syntax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03), pipe `|` is not special and should not be escaped. `]` is kind of special, but only as part of a bracket expression (which you won't have as you escape `[`); outside of it, it shouldn't be escaped.

With these changes, your example [works](https://rextester.com/JHQK62998).

Note that there are other special characters, e.g. parentheses `()` and braces `{}`

Comment: It seems it is VS's std library bug. In VS2017 your code raises an exception

Comment: [Seems to work for me](https://rextester.com/VSLVZ36528) with MSVC compiler, too.

Comment: change 'res' value to 'FindResult', not bool

Comment: Ah, yes, my bad (fixed in the answer). Looks like a bug. Anyway, why don't you just [change the syntax to ECMASCript](https://rextester.com/JDNES96472)? It's more extensively used, and is probably better tested in the implementation.

Comment: It seems ECMASCript works fine, thank you! :)